# Is this the correct way to drive a double coil latching relay?

Tags: polarity, latching-relay

I have found a double coil latching relay which has the following diagram in the datasheet (http://www.fanhar.com/en/uploads/files/FH44L.pdf) :

[image]

I am quite confused by the instruction "The common terminal, positive and negative poles are optional", and then the diagram which shows opposite polarities on each coil for set and reset.

Would the below schematic be the correct way of connecting this double coil latching relay? (switches to be replaced by transistors in final design).  +5V would be the common terminal.  And also whether energising a single coil would be adequate to switch the relay (if it is set in the opposite state)?

[image]

Comment: Please link the datasheet.

Comment: datasheet now linked

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and try to re-interpret what is meant by this:

> The common terminal, positive and negative poles are optional

I think the author may have meant:

"The middle pin is common and its polarity is *interchangeable*."

There are three pins, with a coil (shown by the rectangle) between each pin. In SET, the top coil is positive at the top and negative at the common, while in RESET the same coil is negative at the top and positive at the common.

This diagram is further confusing by showing a polarity for the opposite coil in the same image, however note how they've positioned the polarity indicators *inside* and *outside* the relay outline.

I interpret this as "use the inside polarity markers ***or*** the outside polarity markers, but not both."

Another way to look at this is "the inside polarity markers use a negative common terminal while the outside polarity markers use a positive common terminal."

Your schematic looks correct, according to the outside polarity markers.

That said, do test the relay out of circuit and ensure that this is correct before assuming it is!

Answer (score 1):

The polarity options, as depicted in the data sheet, are difficult to decipher.

Here are the options.

1. Option 1

[image]

2. Option 2

[image]